# Combine data from multiple columns into a single column using Microsoft Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, union

I have a data set in Access which looks like in the below image

```
           col1  col2 col3
    row1   12     23
    row2   34     45   56
    row3   22     33   44
    row4   99
```

But I want it to be like this

```
       row1  12
       row2  23 
       row3  34
       row4  45
       row5  56
       row6  22
       row7  33
       row8  44
       row9  99
```

Is there any way to do this? Your help is highly appreciated as I am new to ms access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by using the UNION SQL query as in the following example:

```
SELECT field_1[, field_2,…]
FROM table_1[, table_2,…]
UNION [ALL]
SELECT field_a[, field_b,...]
FROM table_a[, table_b,…];
```

Pertinent to your case, it should look like the following:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table_1
UNION
SELECT col2
FROM table_1
UNION
SELECT col3
FROM table_1;
```

More reading here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-3856f16c-0a22-43f2-8c23-29ec44acbc05?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
Best regards,

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'll try this. Is there any way to do this without writing queries?

Comment: You can do it manually (just copy-paste), but I thought you are looking for a programmatic solution. Best regards,

Comment: Yes I can do it manually for a small set of data. But when the data set is too large it'll consume too much time. Is there any way to do it using the options available in the top panel(Database tools tab, Design tab or any other tab)?

Comment: This is the simplest way to achieve the result (beyond manual copy-paste). There is a Tab "Create" and sub-item "Query Design" in MS Access 2010. You just paste the query in the editor (SQL View) using your Table name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time for my question.I'll try the suggestions you made. Thanks again.

Comment: You are very welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, please check it answered and upvoted. Many thanks and regards,

Comment: I am unable to upvote since I am new to the site. but i checked it. Thanks again

Comment: Many thanks, I understood. Good luck with your project! Best regards,